# How to declare output as an integer type in export class

Tags: angular, typescript, mean

I need help with a function that needs to return sum of the integers put in by the user in input boxes.

It returns the output as the total but often just concatenates the numbers. e.g. if input1 is 1, and input2 is 2, instead of 3, it would return 12. I know that is happening because I have defined it as a string in the export function. How can I set it to be of integer types and return it as an integer type?

This is my component.ts file. 
   The template defines the input as follows:

```
  <div class="col-md-2"><input ng-model='input1' type="number" 
  required></div>

  <div class="col-md-2"><input ng-model='input2' type="number"         
  required></div>

  <div class="col-md-4">{{Test()}}</div>
```

My export function looks like following:

```
   export class myPageComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(public userInfo : UserService, public pageInfo: 
    PageService, private http: Http ) {
    };

   input1: string = '';
   input2: string= '';

   Test():string {

   return (this.input1 + this.input2);

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code should be work, If you bind input1 and input2 and getting the value of input1 and input2, The value can be a string that time you need to convert the string to a number.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Sum of two integer value';
  input1: number;
  input2: number;

  Test(): number {
    const sum = (!this.input1 ? 0 : +this.input1) + (!this.input2 ? 0 : +this.input2)
    return !sum ? null : sum;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-string)

Comment: I tried your solution. It gives intitial values of '0''s being displayed on the page, which I want to avoid if I can.

Comment: Hi Shohel,  Whenever I use the parseInt function it is giving me the error  Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'". I tried your first solution. it gives 'NaN' still being displayed. It only works when I initialized inputs to 0. But in that situation they displayed 0.

Comment: Hi Shohel,  is there a way to remove the 0 showing under Total. The working solution was helpful!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Try :

`Input1: number;
Input2: number;`

And delete string from function.

Comment: Hi Herdi,  I tried that. It is working partially now. The only problem is in the beginning of when the page is loaded, I am getting 'NaN' displayed for the outcome number of Test function. It only disappears when I enter all the integers as at that time, the total of all the integer appears correctly. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Try `parseInt(this.input1)+parseInt(this.input2)`.

Comment: Hi Herdi. I tried this. it is giving me the error " Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

Comment: set default value to 0;

fo example 
`input 1: number = 0;
input2: number=0;`